# How to bring chrome to foreground from a web app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, minimize, background-foreground

Is there any `windows apps/google chrome flags/google chrome extension/javascript methods` or any other thing that would allow to bring a chrome window **from background(minimized) to foreground** when something happens inside a website. I do have access to the client computer, I could set chrome flags/kiosk mode or anything that would prevent it from opening to foreground if it's possible.

For example I am trying to bring the window to foreground when an order comes in, through a notification (I'm using firebase messages).
I tried to do `window.open()` in `setBackgroundMessageHandler()` in the `service worker` but I get an error in console saying `window is not defined`

If there isn't anything available for chrome to achieve this, would creating a **Microsoft Progressive Web App** with the appropriate permissions allow me to bring that window to foreground from a minimized state?

Comment: You could create a native windows application 
 and use win32 sendmessage/postmessage to focus the window.

Comment: You need to do a `.focus()` on the window object. Without an example of your code, however, it is difficult to know what creates the window and so how you would get hold of that window object. If you are creating the window you want to bringto the front you would assign the result of the `window.open()` to a variable (eg `var myWindow=window.open(...etc...)`) and then run the `.focus()` on that with `myWindow.focus()`.

Comment: @Mr. Zach I don't know how to code a native windows app, would a pwa work?

Comment: @Fat Monk would window.open(), window.focus() work from the setBackgroundMessageHandler() in the serviceworker?

Comment: Which object is the `setBackgroundMessageHandler()` attached to? I'm guessing that there could possibly be object 'scope'/visibility issues but without seeing what is being called from where and in what sequence etc it's difficult to say. Where does the window get opened from initially? Does it always exist already when an order comes in or do you need to create the window if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: As long as there is User Interaction (eg: click on notification) then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient should be available.

Comment: @Fat Monk `setBackgroundMessageHandler()` is in the service worker, I think is the only way it works. In the service worker I cannot access any DOM elements like `window`. I would post the code but there isn't any code, the only method I have in the service worker is `setBackgroundMessageHandler()`. In the main .js file I am using the `onMessage()` method to act when the window is in foreground. I don't know how to act without user interaction when the window is in background. I need a solution either to open a new window or expect one to be open.

Comment: @McMurphy I need something (open chrome window to foreground) to get the user attention without user interaction.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you state your requirement/problem in more detail then people may be able to offer solutions. Are you trying to re-authenticate an expired session? Don't know Firebase but if you subscribed to a SW PushManager *STOP* It's gone!!! I'm looking at the docs as we speak and can't finsd the client.focus() method :-( must be dreaming? Nope: here it is: - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowClient/focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this in the service worker file:

```
   self.addEventListener('push', function (e) {
        if (e.data) {
            var payloadData = e.data.json();
            self.clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true}).then(function (clients) {
                clients[0].postMessage(payloadData); // you can do foreach but I only needed one client to open one window
            });
        }
    });
```

And this in the main.js file:

```
function openNotificationWindow(url) {
    var myWindow = window.open(url);   // Opens a new window
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.location.reload(true);
}

navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    if (typeof event.data.data !== 'undefined') {
        openNotificationWindow(url);
    }
});
```

Now everytime I send a notification either with the window in foreground or in the background the `push` event fires in the serviceworker and then is using `postMessage()` to comunicate with the some main.js file where you have access to the `window` DOM component.

Comment: Exciting! Does this work for both Android and iOS? I understand iOS still does not support notifications for PWA? 

Separately, curious about push notifications... Can a notification launch a PWA from a dormant, unlaunched state, i.e. launch the browser and PWA simultaneously? Can Firebase circumvent Apple to deliver notifications to PWA or is iOS still in control? Or is there a way to implement webhooks on iOS to launch the PWA? This would probably require the app is already running?